# Display data from database using explode in php

Tags: php, sql, explode

I have table named "test". I would like to retrieve data from one column. Each row have multiple data separate with coma. How can i display all the data of column in drop-down?

```
ID | Qualification
1  | BE,Phd,ME
2  | MCA,MBA
3  | MBA
```

How can i display all the data of Qualification column in dropdown? Output should be  like following

```
BE
Phd
ME
MCA
MBA
MBA
```

Comment: Did the answer help you
???

Answer (score 0):

Loop throught your rows and create an array of each row by exploding the rule. Then merge the arrays together. Something like this:

```
//Example data TODO: replace with your table data
$rows[0]['Qualification'] = 'a,b,c'; 
$rows[1]['Qualification'] = 'a,b,c'; 

$qualificationArray = array();
foreach($rows as $rowData)
{
    $rowDataArray = explode(',',$rowData['Qualification']);
    $qualificationArray = array_merge($qualificationArray,$rowDataArray);
}
```

Then use the    qualificationArray to create an dropdown

```
echo '<select name="qualification">';
foreach($qualificationArray as $qualification)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$qualification.'">'.$qualification.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

So the output of this is a dropdown of every value:

```
<select name="qualification">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, read all the data from the database:

```
$quals = array();  // This is the array where we are going to store all the data.

if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `test`"))
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $quals[$row['ID']] = $row['Qualification'];
    }
}
```

The rows are now stored in `$quals` in the form `$quals[ID] = CommaSeperatedQualifications`.

Next, create the drop-down by

1. Iterating through each element in `$quals`.
2. Separating the comma-separated list, `Qualification` into an array of elments, say `$list`.
3. Further iterating through `$list` and printing the `<option>`s of the drop-down.

For example:

```
// now create a drop-down
echo '<select name="list_of_quals">';
foreach ($quals as $id => $value)
{
    $list = explode(',', $value);    
    foreach ($list as $item)
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $item . '</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```